# Wifi on Lenovo L380 is hard blocked but works after ethernet cable was plugged in

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, lenovo

Whenever I reboot/start my laptop wifi in nm-applet is disabled and I cannot enable it (it's not grayed out though).

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I tried a few things already that I found with google like trying to reset the bios and rfkill unblock. Unfortunately nothings works.

I also added this to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Not sure if that's a good idea, definitely didn't help though.

What's interesting as soon as I connect via a wired connection and then after a few seconds unplug it again wifi works. It is unblocked in rfkill and just works absolutely normal.

Here is some output of dmesg. First not working then working after I plug in the ethernet cable.

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl*
[    9.357503] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-33.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.357517] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-32.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.361973] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 31.560484.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    9.394795] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    9.401234] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[    9.457809] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 00:24:d6:f3:b9:02
[    9.485140] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    9.486117] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

the following two lines are added after I plug and unplug the cable

```
[   94.637936] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[   94.637938] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio enabled)
```

Can anybody help me out with this? I'm happy to provide any additional info that is needed.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `lsmod | grep -e idea -e wmi` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hey @chili555, I think I just found the problem. I was running kernel 4.13 and now updated to 4.14 and it seems to work. Currently trying to restart a few time to make sure but yea seems like it is working. Does this makes sense to you that it does not work on 4.13 but does on 4.14? I guess it has to do with the wifi drivers?

Comment: In the world of Linux wireless, anything, it seems, is possible! Glad it's working!